# Unable to load the requested class: session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

my config file looks like this->

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

autoload is ->

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','uri');
```

I am getting the error:

```
Unable to load the requested class: session
```

Please tell me what the actual problem is. I have searched all the previous questions concerned  about this but was not able to fix the problem yet. Thanks in advance .

Comment: what does the error log says?

Comment: First check system/application/libraries/db_Session.php is executable.
If that doesn't work try changing the line in autoload:

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', "db_session");

to

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', "DB_Session");

Please don't hesitate to reply,

Comment: @soul where did you find such path at CI ?

system\libraries\Session.php is the file path at 2.1.3 
and system\libraries\Session\Session.php is at 3.0.0 Dev

Comment: how to check the system/application/libraries/db_Session.php is executable ?

Answer (score 5):

Set your config.php file

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 4):

Your autoload is OK. It doesn't matter if you write it with cap letters or with not capitals.

At config put some random key at

`$config['encryption_key']`

2nd Check your folders permissions.

Tell us which version of CI you are using :)

Currently there are 2 possible reasons ..
1st is that for some reason your CI can't find session class, and second is if its try to load it more than once..

Comment: $config['encryption_key']='zikqwghrdifwher9e7657924xcghg3hdfhgladfhg';

Comment: @user1790439 ok, and which version of CI you use ? the latest 2.1.3 ?

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem .. 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html
here is the usage of sessions. If you have changed something in SYSTEM folder you have to restore it (put the original sys files).

Comment: yes it solves the problem .. something missing in the SYSTEM folder . THANKS

Comment: @user1790439 remember that Sys folder shouldnt be changed.. you have application folder for all your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to load the Session class more than one time.
Check your code for duplicate session's loads. It will solve your problem!
Also make sure you're loading the Session class as a Library and not as a Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$this->load->library('Session');
```

in place of

```
$this->load->driver('Session');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and the problem is in System folder where the session scripts are. You need to move the Session files one level above on the structure tree(files from `System/libraries/session` to `System/libraries`). I know that is the bad practice to change the files and structure of the System, but this was the only solution.

Answer (score -1):

May be following reasons throw this message `Unable to load the requested class - encrypt`

1) on new server some how file name of your lib get changed. so CI doesn't able to find that file

2) may be given lib file doesn't exist on server. so CI doesn't able to find that file

3) might be file name case will be issue.

First check system/application/libraries/Session.php is executable.
If that doesn't work try changing the line in autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','uri');
```

to

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'Session','uri');
```

and try

`$config['encryption_key'] = '`abc1234';

Comment: I Am Getting An 
Error Unable to load the requested class: session . I don't Know What The Actual Problem Is . Please Help Me Out Of This ?