# Unable to load the requested class: Session Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Trying to load Session library in Codeigniter. It seems to be clearly right but actully don't work.
Here's a part of config file:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

As well, ncryption key  variable has already set. Moreover, CI 3 documentation can't give me the way to solve this problem.

---

I've tried to:

1. Set 'sess_save_path' variable to 'ci_sessions'
2. Check folders permissions
3. Check if table 'ci_sessions' exists
4. Use Autoloader class
5. Use class name with capital S

---

It's strange a little, but config says:

```
 /*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Libraries
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These are the classes located in the system/www folder
| or in your application/www folder.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['www'] = array('database', 'email', 'session');
|
| You can also supply an alternative library name to be assigned
| in the controller:
|
|   $autoload['www'] = array('user_agent' => 'ua');
*/
```

And here's a code of autoloader:

```
// Load www
        if (isset($autoload['www']) && count($autoload['www']) > 0)
        {
            // Load the database driver.
            if (in_array('database', $autoload['www']))
            {
                $this->database();
                $autoload['www'] = array_diff($autoload['www'], array('database'));
            }

            // Load all other www
            foreach ($autoload['www'] as $item)
            {
                $this->library($item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've reinstalled CI but it nothing have changed

Comment: why do you have `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` ? , have you tried `$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'` ?

Comment: have you set your encryption key? `$config['encryption_key'] = 'anything_here'`;

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206609/unable-to-load-the-requested-class-session

Comment: Following the documentation: In order to use the ‘database’ session driver, you must also create this table that we already mentioned and then set it as your $config['sess_save_path'] value

Comment: @CodeGodie yes, i have

Comment: `$config['sess_save_path']`  you have this set to `NULL`, why? it should be `ci_sessions`

Comment: @CodeGodie as i said previously - documentation. By the way, i've tried to set it to 'ci_sessions' but gotten the same result

Comment: ok, just make sure you have a table in your database named `ci_sessions` and your `$config['sess_save_path'] = "ci_sessions"`

Comment: @CodeGodie yep, it takes its place

Comment: in your question above, edit it, and provide a list of everything you have tried so that we can continue troubleshooting

Comment: What operating system are you using? In Linux/Unix you have to keep in mind capital letters. The Session class folder has a capital `S`, so when you load it should be `Session` rather than `session`. Try that

Comment: It has no effect. By the way, Session.php file is in the libraries/Session/ directory. Does it matter?

Comment: what is it doing there? for CI3, It should be in : `\system\libraries\Session\Session.php`

Comment: The code you just posted is all commented, just for your information. Also, you might want to post the full error message you are getting.

Comment: thats weird, because your comments say `$autoload['www'] ... ` Where did you download this from? did you do it from http://www.codeigniter.com?

Comment: @IkoTikashi 

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: Session

Comment: @CodeGodie yes, directly from codeigniter.com

Comment: As @CodeGodie stated, `$autoload['www']` should be `$autoload['libraries']`. I suggest you reinstall CI

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: What file are you getting your autoloader code from?

Comment: Thanks everybody, wrong installation caused that error.

Comment: I just downloaded CI3 from this site: http://www.codeigniter.com/download and the comments show: `$autoload['libraries']` not `$autoload['www']`.. i dont know why you have that

Comment: Looks like he replaced 'libraries' with 'www'

Comment: @lkoTikashi seems like it, weird though because he kept saying that he had already re-installed, which made me think his original files were all corrupted, I wonder where he got them from.

Comment: Whole the Loader.php were corrupted, and it's really strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of what you should try:

1. Make sure you load the session library in autload.php: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`
2. Make sure your encryption key is set in cofing.php: `$config['encryption_key'] = 'anything_here'`
3. Make sure your database table is named `ci_sessions` and your sess_save_path is set to that name: `$config['sess_save_path'] = "ci_sessions"`
4. If you are on Unix/Linux, make sure to load your library with capital letters: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('Session');`
5. If nothing works, check that you download and install the right CI3 files from http://www.codeigniter.com/download

Comment: I've try it everything but the problem hasn't gone

Comment: No problem brother, so weird though.. where did you get your initial installation files from?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. It's been downloaded by another programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it on

`config/autoload.php` file and make sure you have this to load the session in Code Igniter 3.

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
```

Make sure you have ci3 installed properly and none of the library files and classes aren't missing. I like using git or composer when installing ci to track changed or you can get the zip or .gz and extract it to use.

Comment: i think you meant: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` not `$autoload['drivers']`

Comment: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session')`  gives the same result: Unable to load the requested class: Session

Comment: in config put random key at $config['encryption_key'] and check your folders permissions.