# Code Igniter with ion auth not working: Unable to load the requested class: Session

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

So while using ionauth on CI I get the error as follows

> Unable to load the requested class: Session

I've done the following things.

Copy the files from IonAuth folder to my CI project

Change the autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'ion_auth', 'uri');
```

In my config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

and

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'uns';
```

But I still get the error and I really have no idea why.

Comment: Possible duplicate. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729202/unable-to-load-the-requested-class-session-in-codeigniter or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079102/unable-to-load-the-requested-class-session-codeigniter-3

Comment: I've applied the solution in both links you mentioned, but the problem still pesists..

Comment: You have not set a session_save_path

Comment: I changed it to `$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';` but still the same error.

Comment: I've also tried `$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'application/cache/';` yet still the same error. What do you think usually causes this? I load the session twice? I've checked that and pretty sure I didn't.

Comment: Use FCPATH, BASEPATH is system folder

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution myself. Still with the same code above, I could get it to work.

So I check the root system/libraries and realized there's no folder `Session` there. Neither is there `Javascript` or `Cache` folders. I was really confused for a while then I copied the folders needed from other project I was working on and it finally worked.

So, I really have no idea how it happened, I only forked the project through git from a friend and he probably removed it somehow and was unaware of it.

Thank you for the help!